# How to move blocks in VSCode 2018? Is that possible?

Tags: text, visual-studio-code, settings, edit

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Do the block select (or as it's also called: cursor block select)
2. Move selected block up/down

[image]

Part 1 is accomplished. But how do I do the second? If I press Alt+UP or Alt+Down I can move only one line, but not the block.

I know this is possible in Sublime3, for example. In Vim you should cut/paste. So what is the strategy for vs code?

Comment: How are you doing the "cursor block select"?  If I use "cursorDownSelect" Shift+downarrow and then ALT+UP/Down it works fine.  The text must be selected I thin, not just a cursor on the lines you want to move.

Comment: I do it as it's described in `cursorColumnSelectDown` (or up). I changed these to mine KB, but effect as on the gif. I tried selecting the text, but ALT+UP/Down just moves one line (as on the screenshot)

Comment: Did you try just "cursorDownSelect" instead? Shift+downarrow.

Comment: @Mark it just selects all the text down to the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this feature is not supported in VScode

Updates:

Recently found a plugin, that can emulate some of the behaviour: MultiLineTricks
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bigous.vscode-multi-line-tricks

Comment: Block move of text is supported in any text-based program under Windows, if you know the right key combinations.

Comment: @RobertHarvey
I would really love to know it :), so if you do, please, post it as an answer, and I would accept it as correct. But meanwhile my search gave me 0 result on that.

Comment: Basically, shift-downarrow gets you the select behavior, ctrl-x cuts, and ctrl-v pastes.  Or, you can just drag the selected block around by holding down the left mouse button.

Comment: That's a bit different: 1) I do not want to use mouse 2) I do not want to copy/paste

I need this block be 'visually' shifted, as it, for example, works in Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode can do this, but you have to **select** instead of adding a cursor.* So:

1. Select with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Up</kbd>

   - (i.e. `cursorDownSelect` / `cursorUpSelect`)
   - The selection needs to include at least one character of the lines you're trying to move, so if you're selecting down and the cursor ends up at the start of a line, or selecting up *starting* from the start of a line, that line is not included in the selection. You can usually just end/start one line further down, respectively.
2. Move lines with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Up</kbd>

   - (i.e. `editor.action.moveLinesDownAction` / `editor.action.moveLinesUpAction`)

---

<sub>* Your description isn't totally clear, and there are no commands containing the words "block select" in the current version of VSCode (1.69.2), but from the gif, it looks like you're doing "Add Cursor Below" (`editor.action.insertCursorBelow`). FWIW, I was also used to doing it like that, coming from Atom.</sub>

---

P.S. I tried some similar techniques and found a bunch of bugs, like that sometimes multiple lines *will* move if you put multiple cursors, but they won't be the right ones. I might file a bug report and add the link here.